# The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated in C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I am trying to send an email but i am getting authentication failure.

Do we need any specific type of authentication for Google mail.

```
[Error in Browser][1]
     // Created Mail message and taken inputs
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from,to,subject,message);
    // Used SMTP Client
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    // Google Port
    client.Port = 587;
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(From.Text, password.Text);
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    client.EnableSsl = true;
    client.Send(mail);
    Label.Text = "Sent Successful";
```

I am getting error near Send(mail)

Comment: You didn't set the SMTP host. `SmtpClient client = new SmptClient("smtp.gmail.com");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not setting the SMTP server address?

Assuming your credentials are correct then you should use `SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")` and `client.Port = 465`. 587 is for TLS